# Wikipedia entity annotator not working in Stanford coreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have setup a local server of Stanford coreNLP library on my system. Although, I am able to get the responses as one can get on the [demo site](http://corenlp.run/). But in my server `wikipedia entity` option is not working. The server gives the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/wikidict.tab.gz" as class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.WikidictAnnotator.<init>(WikidictAnnotator.java:81)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.link(AnnotatorImplementations.java:296)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$63(StanfordCoreNLP.java:517)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getDefaultAnnotatorPool$65(StanfordCoreNLP.java:533)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:118)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:146)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:447)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:146)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:133)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.mkStanfordCoreNLP(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:319)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.access$500(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:50)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:642)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/wikidict.tab.gz" as class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils$GetLinesIterable$1.getReader(IOUtils.java:802)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils$GetLinesIterable$1.<init>(IOUtils.java:760)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils$GetLinesIterable.iterator(IOUtils.java:758)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.WikidictAnnotator.<init>(WikidictAnnotator.java:58)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/wikidict.tab.gz" as class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils$GetLinesIterable.getStream(IOUtils.java:750)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils$GetLinesIterable.access$000(IOUtils.java:719)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils$GetLinesIterable$1.getReader(IOUtils.java:792)
        ... 25 more
```

I have downloaded `wikidict.tab.gz` file, but I am unable to understand how to use it.

Comment: What's the problem? Why downvote? Mention some reasons also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@sv_jan5's answer will work fine, but perhaps easier is downloading and including in your classpath the `English (KBP)` models jar from the download page (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html). The naming is somewhat cryptic -- KBP stands for "Knowledge Base Population," which subsumed the entity linking models and the new relation extraction models.

Direct link is [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-english-kbp-corenlp-2017-06-09-models.jar) for the 3.8.0 version (warning: 500MB download).

Comment: Your answer is cleaner. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to resolve this. You need to do these steps:

1. unzip `stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar`.
2. Download `wikidict.tab.gz` file from [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/kbp/)
3. Copy `wikidict.tab.gz` file in edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp
4. Compress everything into `stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar` file
5. Rerun the server